# Loading jquery datepicker stylesheet

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I am using the `jquery datepicker`. If I put in my `application.css.scss` file

```
@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker';
```

the styles for the datepicker are not loaded.

But if I put

```
@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker.css';
```

the styles are loaded, but when I precompile my assets there is no digest file for `/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.css`
and so it is not included in the `application.css` digest in production. This means the styling does not working in production.

What is the correct way to import this file?  I am using the `sassc` and `jquery-ui-rails` gems.

Comment: Did you add `*= require jquery-ui` in your `application.css` ?

Comment: PraveshKhatri in his case, it would be @import 'jquery-ui'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the following line is in your `application.css`

```
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

Or, if you want to load all of `jquery-ui`, use the following:

```
*= require jquery-ui
```

Once you do that, it shouldn't be necessary to use a sass import so you can remove:

```
@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker.css';
```

If you are only using an `application.css.scss` file, then insert the `*= require jquery-ui/datepicker` into top part of the file so the result looks something like this

```
/*
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
*= require_self
*/
```

Comment: I will try that and get back to you tomorrow

Comment: This worked fine thank you, I added further information to your answer to show what to do if you are using an application.css.scss file.